# Timing of calling .NET WinForms Event Handlers

Tags: .net, winforms

Is it possible for a user to perform some action in WinForms (e.g. clicking a button) and have some arbitrary code executed on the UI thread *before* the event handler for that action is executed on the UI thread? (Edit: I don't want to do this myself.  I want to know if it can actually happen.  As in, do I need to worry about it?)

I'm a little fuzzy on how event handlers get called in .NET for GUI events, and I have run into a situation where that implementation detail is important.

**Edit***
I'm not concerned with how to connect an event handler or even how to raise the event programatically.  I'm concerned with the under-the-hood details of how the event handler that I've already hooked up gets called as a result of the UI action.  More specifically, I'm curious if the calling of the event handler (or the sequence of events that leads up to it) is simply added to the message loop for the form.  It might be easier to show the UI thread "visually"...

Time --------->
Physical Click Detected .......(can other stuff hit the UI thread here)........... Click Event Handler Called

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If this is your own code, just put it in the event handler prior to the other logic...

Comment: There are several possible techniques, not all of them appropriate in every case.  It is very important that you are specific.

Comment: You might want to read up on [`Control.WndProc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx "MSDN reference page") and [windows procedures in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632593.aspx). These are the foundation for all UI event handling in the Win32 API (on which Windows Forms is based).

Comment: Clicking the button causes a message to be posted to the UI message queue. That message will be next up for processing by the message loop, but if you have a timer it might post another message at that precise moment, just ahead of 'yours', or an external message, like for some other application grabbing focus might also occur, but that will be rare. Logic usually doesn't get invoked out of nowhere.

Comment: Quite right, logic doesn't get invoked out of nowhere, although with the stuff I see at work sometimes...
Actually, my question is inspired by the fact that other threads in the app are invoking stuff onto the UI thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options to accomplish this.

Most controls in Windows Forms provide a method that is used to raise the event.  If you subclass the control, you can place your custom code in the method prior to raising the event.

For example, you could subclass `Button`, and override [`OnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.onclick.aspx):

```
override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
    // Your code here...
    base.OnClick(e); // This will raise the Click event
}
```

The other option is to subscribe to the event *first*, and put your code in an event handler.  Event handlers, by default, will call each delegate subscribed in order.

---

> I'm concerned with the under-the-hood details of how the event handler that I've already hooked up gets called as a result of the UI action. More specifically, I'm curious if the calling of the event handler (or the sequence of events that leads up to it) is simply added to the message loop for the form.

When the user clicks a button, the mouse events are posted to the message loop for the application.  The Button handles this message in a `WndProc` override (by handling  a message defined as `WM_REFLECT + WM_COMMAND`).

If your question is "can other code run between the instant the user clicks and an event handler", then yes - code can be running when the user clicks, and that code will continue to run until the message pump can process the messages.

Comment: Not even close to what I'm asking. Please see updated question.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @aaronburro I added an edit that I ~believe~ answers your question - it's not completely clear what you're after here...

Comment: Your edit was useful and almost answers my question...

"can other code run between..." should be changed to "can other code run *on the UI thread* between..."

Comment: @aaronburro And the answer to that is "Yes, the click windows message is put in to a queue of messages to get processed, all of the messages that where queued up but not yet processed at the time the click happened will happen before the click is processed."

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to subclass your button and then add your code to the overriden `OnClick` method (before calling the base `OnClick`). That code will execute before any attached event handlers (for click).